# swap background color of ImageView in Android studio

Tags: android, android-studio, mobile

I'm trying to swap two ImageView's background color. The code I currently have is:

```
    ImageView t1 = findViewById(R.id.t1);
    ImageView f1 = findViewById(R.id.f1);
    int tempt1 = t1.getSolidColor();
    int tempf1 = f1.getSolidColor();
    f1.setBackgroundColor(tempt1);
    t1.setBackgroundColor(tempf1);
```

I have the colors initially set to red and green, but after the swap they just appear white.

Answer (score 1):

```
ImageView t1 = findViewById(R.id.t1);
ImageView f1 = findViewById(R.id.f1);
Drawable tempf1 = f1.getBackground();
f1.setBackground(t1.getBackground());
t1.setBackground(tempf1);
```

Comment: I'm building a rubix cube app and the swaps happen inside a function that moves the cube. So it has to store the current background color in a temporary variable (ie. tempf1) and then swap it with another tile (ie. f1 -> t1). So i'm just trying to find a way to get the current background color.

Comment: Yes it does! Thanks.